# Textual and corresponding image datasets

Tags: data-request

For a small project for multi-modal semantics, I am looking for a dataset which contains textual and visual information about different objects i.e. cars, flowers etc. 
**Requirements** 
Categories - More than 20 objects
Type - jpg, png

Comment: *visual information* Does that mean you need images? If so, in what format. Any size requirements? And what is the *textual information* you want? How much data? It also helps if you give some background what you need them for. Please [read this](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like), then [edit] and make your question **specific**, it may get closed in its current form.

Comment: I have made the required changes @JanDoggen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the requirements, following datasets can be use.

[Pinterest Multimodal Dataset ToolBox](https://github.com/mjhucla/P-Multimodal-Dataset-Toolbox)

---

[Text and Vision (TVGraz) Dataset](http://lrs.icg.tugraz.at/download.php)

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, there are a lot of free datasets published for the field of ["computer vision"](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/Imagedbase.htm#object). Based on the description of your needs, you should maybe take a look at [ImageNet](http://image-net.org/).

Comment: I have already seen ImageNET however it does not provide a description of the objects.

Comment: If the description you want can be a list of labels, you can try [Open Images](https://github.com/openimages/dataset). Here is a viewer to browse the categories : [http://openimages.oldjpg.com/](http://openimages.oldjpg.com/)

Comment: Label can be use to represent a concept or a category which is different from the description. Below I mentioned couple of interesting dataset which I find for my work. We are also going to publish our dataset with our publication